# LnkedTreeMap cannot be cast to mistake

Tags: java, rest, http, gson

[image]

Hereis my code

@Test

```
public void getAllEmployeesTest() throws IOException {
    HttpResponse response = http.get("http://localhost:8087/employee");
    List<Employee> expectedList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    expectedList.add(new Employee(2, "Yashwant", "Chavan", 30, true));
    Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Employee>>() {
    }.getType();
    List<Employee> actualList = gson.fromJson(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()), new ArrayList<Employee>().getClass());
    //Assert.assertEquals(actualList, expectedList);
    System.out.println(expectedList.get(0).isBusy());
    System.out.println(actualList.get(0).isBusy());
}
```

Comment: Please do not use external links. Just post the exception text here instead. Also, you might want to phrase your question as a... you know... question. Somehow highlighting what line causes the exception might also be helpful. Last but not least: You need to show some honest effort. You should not just say: "Code here, exception here, what now?" What have you tried to solve this so far? What is it that you don't understand about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize it with the following code fragment

```
Type typeToken = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Employee>>(){}.getType();
List<Employee> actualList = gson.fromJson(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()), typeToken);
```